# Angular RxJS start polling refresh data if any of the existing data items are still "In Progress"

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

We have a component where we are displaying some data with a status. The data is being provided by a service as an observable array. The service is creating the data stream from two separate api calls and using forkJoin to combine the results into a single stream.

The component has an ag-grid which is consuming the obversable using an async pipe.

Thats all working well.

We have a new requirement that if the status of one or more of the items in the array is "In Progress" we have a requirement to poll every x secs to refresh the data. We then continue to refresh the data, until we have no "In Progress" items then the polling should stop.

This the first time trying to follow a reactive development approach and I am struggling to get my head around how to do some things that I would consider easier with other patterns.

Comment: Can you please provide some code? What you have already tried, the fork join you mentioned, etc.